# Xcode View Debugger: How can I reveal in the hierarchy the selection in the 3-D inspector?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode9, view-debugging

In the Xcode 9 view debugger, I'd like to select a view in the 3-D exploded diagram of views, and then reveal that view in the hierarchy on the left. I know I can "focus" on that view by double-clicking it or selecting "Focus on UIView" from the contextual menu. I know I can also filter by some part of the type of view I want to find, but I actually just want to view I have selected in the context of the complete hierarchy in a single step. I haven't found a way of doing this-- am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the Xcode menu item "Navigate / Reveal in Debug Navigator" to reveal the selected item in the outline view.

Or the convenient keyboard shortcut ⌘ + Shift + D.

Comment: Awesome! can't give you enough upvotes. Anyway, this is something that should be automatic, not with a shortcut or a menu option

Answer (score 0):

Works nice in combination, if you also set the Capture View Hierarchy to say: command + shift + V